# Bundle exception

Tags: java, bundle, noclassdeffounderror, nosuchmethoderror

I am doing some maintenance to a JAVA backend written using bundles. When running the code after doing some software upgrade, I get that error at first:

```
! java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.osgi.framework.BundleContext.registerService (Ljava/lang/Class;Lorg/osgi/framework/ServiceFactory;Ljava/util/Dictionary;) Lorg/osgi/framework/ServiceRegistration;
```

When running it a second time, it gives me the following error:

```
! java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.sap.hilo.orchestration.workspace.HiloWorkspaceFactory
```

Then, it keeps showing the second error for any extra code runs. Any clues how resolve this issue?

Comment: [Maybe this can help with the second error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34413/why-am-i-getting-a-noclassdeffounderror-in-java)

Comment: It seems your new version of `osgi` has `org.osgi.framework.BundleContext.registerService.registerService` with different signature. You need to update your code.

Comment: @llya how can I update the code whereas I do not even run this method.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.osgi.framework.BundleContext.registerService
```

I found an answer to a similar question here: [OSGi: servicereference.getBundle().getVersion() - No such method error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10733483/osgi-servicereference-getbundle-getversion-no-such-method-error)

In the **Import-Package** section of the **pom.xml** file you'll need to change the `org.osgi.framework` version to at least `1.6` or give it a range `[1.6,2.0)`